# Setting a string and removing words from array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I am creating a program that takes a file name as a parameter. One of the functions it performs is removing a specific word from the imported file based on a user's input. I have been able to remove the word, but how do I make these changes show up when I print the array list ? Do I use "strings.set"?

It just prints the original array list

Below is the code:

```
public void word() {
    int e;
    Scanner removeWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What word would you like to remove?");
    String word = removeWord.next();
    for (e = 0; e < strings.size(); e++) {
        if (strings.get(e) == word) {
            strings.remove(word);

            // strings.set(e, remove(word));
        }
    }
    System.out.print(strings);
}
```

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string values, not the `==` operator.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You mention *array* in your title and tags, but it smells like you're using an ArrayList. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use == when comparing Strings. Use the .equals() method instead.

Edit: Also, the way you're looping over your String array, won't you skip over a String every time you remove one?